# How to delete content of directory using ftw

Tags: linux, nftw

We can delete non-empty directory using ftw using FTW_DEPTH. But I want to delete content of directory but not directory itself some thing similar to rm -rf dir/*.

How to achieve this using nftp/ftw ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (**WARNING, no confirm are required**) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ftw(argv[1], list, 1);
  return 0;
}

int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type) {
  if(type != FTW_D) {
    cout << "Deleting " << name << endl;
    remove( name );
  }
return 0;
}
```

And call your app :

> ./main path_to_delete

Comment: Hi Alban thanks for the reply, this holds good if the contents of the directory are only regular files. I was looking for a case where we can have directories also inside the main directory

Comment: I added following code for deleting regular files inline `int helper_routine(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf) { if (!S_ISDIR(sb->st_mode))  remove(fpath);  } return 0; }`